# How to append value of one input field into another input field's value with vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two input fields and I want to add the value of one them to another. Here is what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<input id="server" type="text" value="www.google.com">
<input id="port" type="text">
<button onclick="appendPort()">Save</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getPort() {
  let portValue = document.getElementById('port').value;
}

function appendPort(portValue) {
  getPort();
  console.log(portValue);
}
```

So onClick, I'm expecting the value of the first input field to be `www.google.com123` if the value of the second input field is `123`. Why does `portValue` log as `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appendPort` doesn't recieve an argument. It should use the return value of `getPort`:

```
function appendPort() {
    var portValue = getPort();                     // get the value returned by getPort and store it in portValue
    console.log(portValue);
}
```

and `getPort` should return it:

```
function getPort() {
    return document.getElementById('port').value;  // return something to be used by appendPort
}
```

Comment: functions need to `return` things.

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy Ooops! Didn't notice that `getPort` should return the value.

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy You should really read about **functions**.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the portValue local variable in the getPort, so it is not alive in appendPort function. You should use it as global. Second, you using portValue as parameter in the appendPort function, so it hide the original portValue. You called the appendPort without parameter, so in the function it will be default undefined.

Try this:

```
<script>
let portValue = 3; // set to global
function getPort() {
   portValue = document.getElementById('port').value;
}

function appendPort() { // without parameter
  getPort();
  console.log(portValue);
}
</script>
<input id="server" type="text" value="www.google.com">
<input id="port" type="text">
<button onclick="appendPort()">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`portValue` is undefined because the function `getPort` does not return anything. At the end of the function, add the line  `return portValue;` Then change `appendPort` so that it takes no input and add this line at the beginning `var portValue = getPort();`